# Inform mod_perl application that the apache server has restarted

Tags: perl, apache2, mod-perl

What's the best way (assuming there is one) to inform a mod_perl application that the apache web-server it's running under recently restarted?

I ask because when I restart the server I'd like to clear memcached, however in that case, I need to inform the application that memcached has reset so that the application can initialise the data again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this sort of logic in a startup file.  This file will be executed on Apache (re)start.  In your Apache config:

```
 PerlPostConfigRequire /home/httpd/perl/lib/startup.pl
```

[More info at http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/handlers/server.html#Startup_File](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/handlers/server.html#Startup_File)